# mysql sort functions properly when datatype is bigint(8) but fails as bigint(20)

Tags: mysql, sorting, biginteger

I am using a column to store UNIX timestamp **in seconds** (divide it by 1000). I found bigint datatype to be large enough to store it. I created it using

```
 ...
 createTimeStamp bigint,
 ...
```

However, when I ran

```
show create table tablename
```

It had created it as bigint(20). I did not notice it until my sort started running into problems. I then modified the schema to make it bigint(8) expressly as in:

```
alter table tablename modify createTimeStamp bigint(8)
```

and the sort functions well.

I researched and realized that bigint(20) has nothing to do with storage and is only used for display by padding spaces. If so, why is the sort not functioning when using bigint(20)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql alludes to errors when using numbers that exceed 64 bits.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-overview.html

> BIGINT[(M)] [UNSIGNED] [ZEROFILL]
>
> A large integer. The signed range is -9223372036854775808 to
>   9223372036854775807. The unsigned range is 0 to 18446744073709551615. 
>        ...
>        ...
>
> Some things you should be aware of with respect to BIGINT columns:
>
> All arithmetic is done using signed BIGINT or DOUBLE values, so you 
>   should not use unsigned big integers larger than
>   9223372036854775807 (63 bits) except with bit functions! If you do
>   that, some of the last digits in the result may be wrong because of
>   rounding errors when converting a BIGINT value to a DOUBLE.

Comment: This is not an issue with my problem. The number is well within the range and I am storing the number after getting a whole integer. I mean I am not passing a floating point number to mysql to do its conversion to int. Also, there is only a sql comparison as in a where clause with a `BIGINT_column > somevalue` and no expression is involved anywhere using the BIGINT column.

Comment: The issue is not with your data, it is with a storage mechanism that is not suitable, since you are using double precision numbers to store your values hen using BIGINT.. Try appending a sort direction to your query to see if it ake a difference (. eg, " ...ORDER BY myfield ASC"

Comment: I fixed it with using BIGINT(8) expressly and there are no problems. I was using asc/desc earlier too and it did not fix the problem. You did point in the right direction and so I am accepting your answer.

Comment: @Sam what was the issue, please?  It's not clear based on the information you've provided so far.

Comment: @Michael - I am using Node mysql module on the server side and dynamically generate a query string which includes an order by clause. One of the tables uses  an integer field to store UNIX timestamp but only the seconds and not milliseconds.  When I use order by clause on this column, it does not sort properly when the column is stored as a BIGINT(20)  but does sort when BIGINT(8) is used.  To be frank, now that it works and because I should not have used the default BIGINT(20) in the first place, I stopped debugging further.